# Flash Builder, doing a quiz , randomize questions and points

Tags: xml, flash-builder

I have created a quiz on Flash Builder. I have a total of 40 questions, which i hope my quiz will randomize and show only 10 questions.

Each of my question has 3 multiple choice answers which contains 10 marks, 5 marks and 1mark. So is there anyway i can add some coding in order to let it accumulate the score after 10 questions?

Comment: I understand,  but you should post a code or more information, because this could have many solutions. For example, you could use a global variable...

Comment: I do not think you can post the 40 questions, but you can tell if you use states, various components, or a single. So, the idea is to not post the 40 questions, but at least a pseudocode. In minutes you'll upload an example (made in Flex 3) to my github repository.

Comment: Please look at the code I posted you, is an example of a simple quiz, with 5 questions, when you get to the last, click the button **calculateTotal** and will show you the quantity of correct answers, this quantity is calculated when you click the button, but you can change it, for example, you could use a global variable with the score, or use an array with the user answers, or as I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example, maybe will be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.containers.Panel;
        private var arrAnswers:Array = ["Red","Yellow","Blue","Red","Orange"];  //this array contains the answers
        private var arrComp:Array;
        private var lastChild:Number = 0;

        public function init():void{
            arrComp = [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5];
            main.selectedChild = arrComp[0];
        }

        public function processQ(i:Number):void{
            lastChild = lastChild + i;
            if(lastChild==4){
                next.enabled = false;
                prev.enabled = true;
            }else if(lastChild==0){
                prev.enabled = false;
                next.enabled = true;
            }else{
                next.enabled = true;
                prev.enabled = true;
            }
            main.selectedChild = arrComp[lastChild];
            updateSelected();
        }

        private function updateSelected():void{
            var tmpArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            tmpArr.addItem("1:" + String(q1.radioGroup.selectedValue));
            tmpArr.addItem("2:" + String(q2.radioGroup.selectedValue));
            tmpArr.addItem("3:" + String(q3.radioGroup.selectedValue));
            tmpArr.addItem("4:" + String(q4.radioGroup.selectedValue));
            tmpArr.addItem("5:" + String(q5.radioGroup.selectedValue));
            lstSelected.dataProvider = tmpArr;
        }

        public function calculateTotal():void{
            var i:int = 0;
            var nCorrect:int = 0;
            for each(var obj:QuestionComponent in arrComp){
                if(obj.radioGroup.selectedValue==arrAnswers[i]){
                    nCorrect++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            lblC.text = "Correct answers: " + nCorrect.toString();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:ViewStack id="main" width="100%">
    <local:QuestionComponent title="Question N°1" id="q1" />
    <local:QuestionComponent title="Question N°2" id="q2" />    
    <local:QuestionComponent title="Question N°3" id="q3" />    
    <local:QuestionComponent title="Question N°4" id="q4" />    
    <local:QuestionComponent title="Question N°5" id="q5" />        
</mx:ViewStack>
<mx:HBox width="100%">
    <mx:Grid width="100%" verticalAlign="bottom">
        <mx:GridRow horizontalAlign="left" width="100%" verticalAlign="bottom">
            <mx:GridItem horizontalAlign="left" width="33%">
                <mx:Button id="prev" click="processQ(-1)" label="Prev" enabled="false" width="100%"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem horizontalAlign="center" width="33%">
                <mx:Button id="tot" click="calculateTotal()" label="GetTotal" width="100%"/>
            </mx:GridItem>              
            <mx:GridItem horizontalAlign="right" width="33%">
                <mx:Button id="next" click="processQ(1)" label="Next" width="100%"/>    
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</mx:HBox>
<mx:List id="lstSelected" width="200" height="200"/>
<mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
    <mx:Text text="Correct answers: 0" id="lblC" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="50"/>  
</mx:HBox>
```

}

And this is a component **QuestionComponent**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="radioGroup"/>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:RadioButton id="radioButton1" label="Red" group="{radioGroup}" />
        <mx:RadioButton id="radioButton2" label="Orange" group="{radioGroup}" />
        <mx:RadioButton id="radioButton3" label="Yellow" group="{radioGroup}" />
        <mx:RadioButton id="radioButton4" label="Green" group="{radioGroup}"/>
        <mx:RadioButton id="radioButton5" label="Blue" group="{radioGroup}" />      
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Panel>
```

If you want to test this example please visit this **[LINK](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/blob/master/QuizExample/Deploy/QuizExample.swf?raw=true)** (**[source](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/tree/master/QuizExample)**).

**Edited**

You must consider the following:
**(quizz.mxml)**

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication ...>
......
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var answersArr:Array = null; 

        public function init():void{
            answersArr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
......
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

For each VIEW (qns1,qns2,....qns10):

```
<s:View ....>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var selected:int = 0;
            public function next():void{
                parentDocument["answersArr"][0] = selected;
                navigator.pushView(qns2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button x="230" y="345" label="Next" click="next()"/>
....
    <s:Button x="33" y="135" width="261" label="A." click="{selected=1;}"/>
    <s:Button x="33" y="208" width="261" label="B." click="{selected=2;}"/>
    <s:Button x="31" y="283" width="261" label="C." click="{selected=3;}"/>
....
</s:View>
```

And finally (summary.mxml):

```
<s:View ...>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        public var selected:int = 0;
        public function view_activateHandler():void{
            var arr:Array = parentDocument["answersArr"] as Array;
            var tempArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var j:int = 1;
            for each(var i:int in arr){
                tempArr.addItem("Question N°" + j.toString() + " - Answer: " + i.toString());
                j++;
            }
            answers.dataProvider = tempArr;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
....
    <s:List x="27" y="224" width="266" height="140" id="answers" />
</s:View>
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE EXAMPLE! Where do i put the codes in? i have totally no background information about Flash Builder.

Comment: This code was created in Flex Builder 3, but you can import in Flash builder 4.x too. Please, download the source code **[HERE](https://github.com/gastonf/GRepo/blob/master/QuizExample/Zip/Source.rar?raw=true)**, to import a complete project, maybe this [LINK1](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_4.html) [LINK2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4ef5411412477fbf920-8000.html) will be useful. Download a rar file, and decompress into same folder, then go to the Flas Builder, and click left mouse button, "Import.."->"Existing P.."

Comment: Hello, i have good news, please see the edited post for more explanation, you can download the code from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/quizz.rar).

Comment: I just checked, but then the questions did not appear on the page for question 1-10?

Comment: i still have no idea how to add in the questions and randomizing it.

Comment: How do i insert my questions? in each part?

Comment: Could it be possible if you add some questions in the file to let me explore ? Thanks

Comment: Because I have 40questions, but i would only like to have 10 questions on display. Thus, doing the randomization of 10questions. Meanwhile, it will also accumulate the score of each question.

Comment: Please go to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33093/flex-mobile) room

Comment: I can't chat, because I think i have less than 20reputations?

Comment: Please see my account here (click over "Gaston F." and then contact me with my email, because I can not understand what you need, so we use gtalk or gmail. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find your gmail to contact you.

Comment: so what is your email?

Comment: I have send you an email. Thank you.

Comment: Hi gaston, i just send you an email. I have some problems regarding adjusting the screen size automatically for all android phones. Please reply me asap. :D